# How to find next Xth of month after a date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two parameters :

1. a date (Ex : 22/11/2016)
2. a day number (Ex : 25)

I want to find the next 25th of month after 22/11/2016: `25/11/2016`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select trunc(date '2016-11-22', 'month') + 25
from dual;
```

`trunc(date '2016-11-22', 'month')` will return the first of the month, the `+ 25` will then add the desired 25 days.

If the meaning of the second parameter depends on the "comparison" date you can do something like this:

```
select case 
          when extract(day from date '2016-11-22') >= 25 then 
             add_months(trunc(date '2016-11-22', 'month'), 1) + 25 
          else trunc(date '2016-11-22', 'month') + 25
        end as next_date
from dual;
```

Of course you would replace the hardcoded values for the date and the "number" of days with variables or column values.

This example:

```
with sample_data (the_date, num_days) as (
   select date '2016-11-22', 25 from dual union all
   select date ' 2016-11-26', 22 from dual union all
   select date ' 2016-11-26', 3 from dual
)
select the_date, num_days, 
       case 
          when extract(day from the_date) >= num_days then 
             add_months(trunc(the_date, 'month'), 1) + num_days - 1
          else trunc(the_date, 'month') + num_days - 1
        end as next_date
from sample_data;
```

will return:

```
THE_DATE    | NUM_DAYS | NEXT_DATE  
------------+----------+------------
2016-11-22  |       25 | 2016-11-25 
2016-11-26  |       22 | 2016-12-22 
2016-11-26  |        3 | 2016-12-03
```

Comment: But what if my date is 22/11/2016 and i want the next 3rd of month (03/12/2016) ?

Comment: Not a correct answer. If the input is 2016-11-26 than the output should be 2016-12-25. Zedfax - Please verify.

Comment: Seems like your date `22/11/2016 ` is fixed and you want all the dates after that case there cannot be a generic solution. You need to twist and turn your query to achieve your desired dates

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Because i need it to be later than the date in parameter.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you very much. I'll try it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it does exactly what i was looking for. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

it can solve your problem:

```
 select 
    (
    case 
      when trunc (:yourdate-trunc(:yourdate,'month'))+1 <:urNum then
      trunc(:yourdate,'month')+:urNum-1
        else
         trunc(last_day(:yourdate))+:urNum
          end) 
      from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
LAST_DAY(<<a date>>) + <<a day number>> + 1
```

[LAST_DAY](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions096.htm) gives you the last day of give, months (e.i. November, 30th), then add 1 day to get 1st of December plus your day number.

Comment: That would yield December, 25th for the sample data in the question.

Comment: Yes, but as already noticed the question is not really clear.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this

```
WITH tmp AS 
(
    SELECT TO_DATE('22/11/2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY') date_col FROM DUAL
)
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(date_col,'DD') > '25' 
        THEN TO_DATE('25' || TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(date_col, 1), '/MM/yyyy'), 'DD/MM/YYYY')  
        ELSE TO_DATE('25' || TO_CHAR(date_col, '/MM/yyyy'), 'DD/MM/YYYY') END date_col_new
FROM tmp;
```

If your input (25) is number, you could use `TO_CHAR(your_input)` instead of `'25'`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
WITH dates AS (SELECT to_date('30/11/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt FROM dual UNION ALL
               SELECT to_date('03/11/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt FROM dual UNION ALL
               SELECT to_date('31/10/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt FROM dual UNION ALL
               SELECT to_date('29/11/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt FROM dual UNION ALL
               SELECT to_date('31/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt FROM dual),
       dom AS (SELECT 25 day_of_month FROM dual UNION ALL
               SELECT 31 day_of_month FROM dual UNION ALL
               SELECT 30 day_of_month FROM dual UNION ALL
               SELECT 03 day_of_month FROM dual UNION ALL
               SELECT 01 day_of_month FROM dual),
       res AS (SELECT dates.dt starting_dt,
                      dom.day_of_month,
                      add_months(TRUNC(dates.dt, 'mm'),
                                 CASE WHEN to_char(dates.dt, 'dd') >= dom.day_of_month
                                           THEN 1
                                      ELSE 0
                                 END) month_of_end_dt
               FROM   dates
                      CROSS JOIN dom)
SELECT starting_dt,
       day_of_month,
       month_of_end_dt + least(day_of_month, to_number(to_char(last_day(month_of_end_dt), 'dd'))) - 1 next_date
FROM   res
ORDER BY starting_dt, day_of_month;

STARTING_DATE DAY_OF_MONTH NEXT_DATE
------------- ------------ ----------
31/10/2015               1 01/11/2015
31/10/2015               3 03/11/2015
31/10/2015              25 25/11/2015
31/10/2015              30 30/11/2015
31/10/2015              31 30/11/2015
03/11/2015               1 01/12/2015
03/11/2015               3 03/12/2015
03/11/2015              25 25/11/2015
03/11/2015              30 30/11/2015
03/11/2015              31 30/11/2015
29/11/2015               1 01/12/2015
29/11/2015               3 03/12/2015
29/11/2015              25 25/12/2015
29/11/2015              30 30/11/2015
29/11/2015              31 30/11/2015
30/11/2015               1 01/12/2015
30/11/2015               3 03/12/2015
30/11/2015              25 25/12/2015
30/11/2015              30 30/12/2015
30/11/2015              31 30/11/2015
31/01/2016               1 01/02/2016
31/01/2016               3 03/02/2016
31/01/2016              25 25/02/2016
31/01/2016              30 29/02/2016
31/01/2016              31 29/02/2016
```

What this does is it first finds out the month that the new date is going to be in by comparing the day you're after with the date being compared with. (ie. if the day of the date you want to get to is already past the day of the starting date, add one to the month, otherwise add nothing).

Once you have that, it's a simple matter of adding the number of days you're trying to get to.

**I have assumed that if the month doesn't have the full number of days (eg. February, April, June, September, November) then you'll want whatever the last day of that month is instead.**

Therefore, we'll pick whichever is lower - the last day of the month or the day you want to get to. We have to subtract one from that result since we want to include the first of the month in the count.